# Can we give two files as input while using JasperStarter

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperstarter

I am using JasperStarter to create pdf from several jrprint files and then print it using JasperStarter functtions.
I want to create one single pdf file with all the .jrprint files.
If I give command like:
jasperstarter pr a.jprint b.jprint -f pdf -o rep

It does not recognise the files after the first input file.
Can we create one single output file with many input jasper/jrprint files?

Please help.
Thanks,
Oshin

Comment: @DanFromGermany Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](http://jasperstarter.cenote.de/usage.html#The_command_process_pr), this is not possible:

> **The command process (pr)**
>   The command process is for processing **a** report.

In direct comparison to the command for compiling:

> **The command compile (cp)**
>   The command compile is for compiling one report **or all reports** in a directory.